# What does the special word do in Monster Seeking Monster?

Tags: jackbox-party-pack-4

On some nights in Monster Seeking Monster the narrator will give a special word. She says that it has something to do with a monster's power but none of the monsters have a power that has to do with a secret word. What does the secret word do and which monster can use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does a cool lightning effect that's just cosmetical and doesn't affect gameplay

Source: https://twitter.com/misterarnie/status/1322616370178232321?lang=en

Comment: Here's a confirmation from a developer: https://twitter.com/misterarnie/status/1322616370178232321?lang=en